# Detecting Spot Colors

Tags: adobe-photoshop, pdf

How do I find whether or not spot colors have been used in a PDF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Adobe **Acrobat** choose `View > Tools > Print Production` and click **Ink Manager**

I don't believe apps such as Reader or Preview will allow you to verify colors.

Photoshop **rasterizes everything** in a PDF when you open it unless it is a Photoshop PDF saved with editing capabilities enabled. There's no way to use Photoshop. In fact, often Photoshop will *degrade* a PDF if used. Using Photoshop to verify colors within a PDF is haphazard at best.

Comment: I noticed that in acrobat I had the ability to "Convert All Spots to Process" - what happens when you use this feature?  Does it try to approximate each of the individual spot colors and decide what it would be in CMYK and then convert it to that value?  When I tried to do this the spot colors dropped out completely of the document.

Comment: It depends on the way the file is constructed. Some Spot colors have internal CMYK build values. If those are present, then Acrobat will convert the spot based on those values and the assigned color profile. If a spot color is not possible in CMYK (such as fluorescents or metallics) it may drop out.